# How to capture when have outgoing SMS programmatically on Android?

Tags: android

I want to monitor Event "OUTGOING SMS"
Programmatically?

I have got Event "Incoming SMS" just like this code.

```
public class IncomingSmsCaptureApp extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_SMS = "android.provider.Telephony.NEW_OUTGOING_SMS";
private static final String ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

private String action;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // ---get the SMS message passed in---
    action = intent.getAction();
    if (ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED.equals(action)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
            }
            // ---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        onSending(context, intent);
    }

}

public void onSending(Context context, Intent intent) {
    action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_SMS)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Test Capture SMS Sending Success",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

I use this code for monitor Event "OUTGOING SMS".
It is not work.

My application want to get "Action" when have "OUTGOING SMS".
Is it possible?
I didn't find answer for this problem.

Help me please.
Sorry for my bad English.